# PDE - Fritz John Problem 4 Chapter 2, linear operators and common solutions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, differential-operators

I'm trying to do this problem:

---

Let the operators $L_1, L_2$ be defined by  $$L_1u=au_x+bu_y+cu ~~~; L_2u=du_x+eu_y+f_u$$

where $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are constants with $ac-bd\neq 0$. Prove that

1. The equations $L_1u=w_1, L_2u=w_2$ have a common solution $u$, if $L_1w_2= L_2w_1$

(Hint: By linear transformation reduce to the case $a = e = 1, h = d = 0.$)

2. The general solution of $L_1L_2 u=0$ has the form $u=u_1+u_2$, where $L_1u_1=0, 
   L_2u_2=0.$

---

In (1), given $u_1, u_2$ solutions of $Lu=w_1, Lu=w_2$, respectively, then starting with $L_1w_2=L_2w_1$ and replacing with $L_1u_1=w_1, L_2u_2=w_2$ i got

$$(ae+bd)({u_2}_x-{u_1}_x)+ad({u_2}_{xx}-{u_1}_{xx})+(af+cd)({u_2}_x-{u_1}_x)+(bf+ce)({u_2}_y-{u_1}_y)+be({u_2}_{yy}-{u_1}_{yy})+cf(u_2-u_1)=0$$

i don't know what else to do.

In part (2), i don't know where to start

I would need some hint.

Comment: Under (1), do you mean $L_2w_1 = L_1w_2$?

Comment: yes. i have just eddited it

Comment: Thanks!  ***Cheers!!!***

Comment: Your explanation of what you have done isn't very clear. For $(1)$, $$L_{1} u = w_{1} \implies L_{2} L_{1} u = L_{1} w_{1}, \quad L_{2} u = w_{2} \implies L_{1} L_{2} u = L_{1} w_{2}$$ Therefore, if you can show that $L_{1} L_{2} u = L_{2} L_{1} u$ then you are done. Then $(2)$ follows from $(1)$.

Comment: In your first implication you mean $L_2L_1u=L_2w_1$, right? I cannot see why showing that $L_1L_2u=L_2L_1u$ would let me conclude